# Alfresco unique constraint validation adding content to webform with xs:unique

Tags: validation, webforms, alfresco

Is it possible with standard Alfresco code to perform schema validations when adding new content to a webform? (the webform is associated with the schema file)

I have a simple schema file with 3 elements that must be unique. I've found out that I can use xs:unique to perform this validation and ensure that each element is unique, however Alfresco does not perform this validation at all.

I can submit the content with repeated fields anywhere.

I've been digging the internet to find a solution and it is possible to tackle this issue messing a little with Alfresco extensions, however I would like to know if is there any other way.

Does someone experienced this issue?

Comment: How are you talking with Alfresco, through REST? You're expecting server side validation for uniqueness, am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yes. Well, I am not sure if this is server side validation. The webform creates content. Content is created within a contract (schema/XSD). In my schema I have a element username and a structure that validates this element is unique. This validation can be performed in Alfresco frontend/UI? For example, you set a positive integer type for an element, if you insert a string, when you deselect the text area (un-focus it) it prints a red exception saying that you must insert a positive integer in that text area. Why the xs:unique validation does not work this way?

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom validation in this custom validation you need to check whether your elements are unique or not please refer this [documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-share-form-field-validation-handlers.html) for custom validations.

Comment: This should be implemented in a Alfresco extension?

Comment: Yes, you should use the custom extension. You can call your server-side code validation from javascript.